# JQuery get $(this) value from nested DIV

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of the nested DIVs called "info" below. The problem is that it is showing both AWS and Azure in the response. I thought using `$(this)` would help, but I obviously have something screwed up.

```js
$(".cont-checkbox").click(function() {

  $(".cont-checkbox > label > div.info").each(function() {
    let str = $(this).text();
    console.log(str);
  });

  // will send str to Ajax request

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont-bg">

  <div class="cont-main">

    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="24" id="serviceCheckbox1">
      <label for="serviceCheckbox1">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <span class="cover-checkbox">
              <svg viewBox="0.5 1 12 12">
                <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
              </svg>
            </span>
            <div class="info">AWS</div>
            <div class="infoSubTitle">Amazon Web Services</div>
          </label>
    </div>

    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="38" id="serviceCheckbox2">
      <label for="serviceCheckbox2">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <span class="cover-checkbox">
              <svg viewBox="0.5 1 12 12">
                <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
              </svg>
            </span>
            <div class="info">Azure</div>
            <div class="infoSubTitle">Microsoft Azure</div>
          </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf4046/defx01nh/15/)

Comment: instead of your `each` you want to use `$(this).find(" > label > div.info").text();`  Also your html is invalid, you can't have block elements inside a `label`

Comment: Okay, progress.  Thank you!